# Setup proxy with local CA certificate on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssl-certificate, apt, curl, ubuntu-20.04

In our company, we have a proxy server with a self-signed CA certificate implementing MITM inspection. No internet connection is possible without this proxy server. My certificate installation process on a fresh install of Ubuntu server 20.04 (omitting `sudo`):

```
apt install ca-certificates
openssl x509 -inform der -in CompanyCA.cer -out CompanyCA.crt
openssl x509 -inform der -in CompanyRootCA.cer -out CompanyRootCA.crt
cp CompanyCA.crt CompanyRootCA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
update-ca-certificates
```

This seems to have no effect. `curl` and `wget` still require the `-k` and `--no-certificate-check` options and `apt`'s certificate verification fails. Timezone, date and time are set correctly.

Is there something else I could try (except ignoring it)?

Comment: Check if the certificate has been added to /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt, if not run update-ca-certificates with `-v`

Comment: also check that the cert and chain is the one you expect with `openssl s_client -connect -showcerts`, or with `curl --cacert`

Comment: I suggest you also check the system logs for any error messages related to the certificate validation process. It's possible that there's another issue causing these errors.

Comment: @AlexanderPavluchenko Check the system logs with `dmesg`? I already checked `dmesg`, but didn't spot any errors relating to `apt`.

Comment: @symcbean I verified both certificates are in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`. But `curl` and `apt` still are complaining.

Comment: I solved this by copying over the certificates from another machine. Our company-internal docs are apparently outdated and are recommending old certificates.